# How to list mosquitto clients using dynamic security feature?

Tags: mosquitto

I got the Dynamic Security of mosquitto mostly working.  However, I'm not sure how to use the `listClients` command through the `json` approach, as explained here:

https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/plugins/dynamic-security/README.md#list-clients

For example, this command works perfectly for me and it lists all the users stored in my `/var/lib/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json` file:

```
mosquitto_ctrl -u steve -P Pass1234 dynsec listClients
```

However, when I use the JSON approach like this:

```
mosquitto_pub -u steve -P Pass1234 -t '$CONTROL/dynamic-security/v1' -m '{"commands":[{"command": "listClients","verbose":false,"count": -1,"offset": 0}]}';
```

The result is no output at all.

How do I get the list of clients through the JSON approach as indicated in the `README.md` file above?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are running an equivalent `mosquitto_sub` command to see the response? `mosquitto_pub` will never return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the answer to the question in the comments is "no"

You need to also run:

```
mosquitto_sub -u steve -P Pass1234 -v -t '$CONTROL/#'
```

To subscribe to the correct response topic.

The `mosquitto_pub` command will only ever publish messages, it will subscribe to any topics and print out messages.

Comment: That worked!  Can you explain why the subscribed topic is `$CONTROL/#`?  I would have guessed it to be `$CONTROL/dynamic-security/v1` so that it is same as the topic that I published to.

Comment: `#` is a wildcard meaning any number of topic levels, so `$CONTROL/#` matches all topics that start with `$CONTROL/`. I wasn't 100% sure what topic the response would be on which is why I used the wildcard and the `-v` option which causes `mosquitto_pub` to print the topic before the message.

Comment: Ooooh!!!!  the -v option discloses this topic `$CONTROL/dynamic-security/v1/response`.  So then I `mosquitto_sub -u steve -P Pass1234 -t $CONTROL/dynamic-security/v1/response`, which also worked!  So I'll use the `$CONTROL/dynamic-security/v1/response` to ignore anything not related to dynamic security